# Use REPLACE() function with laravel Database: Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

In one of my table columns I have '_' values. But I need to replace them with space. This is my code.

```
$crimes = DB::table('crimes')
                    ->addSelect('crime_code')
                    ->addSelect('areas.name as area')
                    ->addSelect(REPLACE('danger_level', "_", " "))
                    ->addSelect('date')
                    ->addSelect('status')
                    ->get()
```

But I'm getting this error,

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\REPLACE()

I'm trying to use laravel [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) and [MySQL REPLACE() function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php). It would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `selectRaw()` to insert sql to your query

```
$crimes = DB::table('crimes')
                    ->addSelect('crime_code')
                    ->addSelect('areas.name as area')
                    ->selectRaw("REPLACE(danger_level, '_', ' ')")
                    ->addSelect('date')
                    ->addSelect('status')
                    ->get()
```